# carousel for more view Thumbnail images

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I am looking for a way to add a carousel to my MORE VIEW Thumbnail images of my Magneto website . These Thumbnails Images are at the bottom of main Image of product pages .
I had a look on the internet could not find anything to do so-  as a result wanted to give a try here.

Thank for any help !

Comment: which plugin you have used for carousel?

Comment: No have not used anything yet . Need a way to align these thumbnail images as they look quite odd particularly if they are in large numbers.I dont think there are any Magento plugin for this ?